# How can I parse a string that contains the same symbol I use as a delimiter?

Tags: java, string, parsing, split, delimiter

I would like to put some Strings together and split them again afterward. The character I would like to use as a marker for the point where the String is put together should also be allowed to occur in the Strings.

Example: 
We want to send a message to someone else. There should not only be the message itself, but also some information about the sender and the receiver.

So we have three Strings: sender, receiver, and text. As a delimiter I use `$`. That means that the merged String would have the following syntax: sender$receiver$text

As long as there is no `$` in sender, receiver, or text, everything is fine and there won’t be a problem when splitting the String again. But when there is a `$` in one of the Strings, an unexpected output will be given.

How can I avoid this problem without just creating the rule that `$` is not allowed to be used?

Comment: Why not use a character which will be forbidden in the fields?

Comment: $ is only an example. I don’t want to ban any character at all

Comment: You could group with a combination of characters that you would then forbid, like "!@#", so your merged String would be sender!@#receiver!@#text

Comment: If you are both handling the string on the sending and receiving side then you could escape the delimiter first in the text, "I made $100" -> "I made \$100"

Comment: i would use somthing like '|*0$0*|' or any sequence as separator , or go for an  js object

Comment: The usual approach is to use some escaping. You could convert all `$` for example to `\U+00024`. On the other end, you can split it and unescape it again.

Comment: @ayrton of course I could do this and it would be very unlikely that for example the name of the sender contains that expression but I ca not be sure about it

Comment: You can serialize it and then deserialize it on the receiver's side. You could use JSON for that.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj but that means that I can’t use \U+00024 or I have to escape that character again and so on...

Comment: @Nightfighter001, escaping that string would yield `\\UU+00024`

Comment: A proper format/language/notation, like @MCEmperor suggested, should be your approach. JSON, XML, YAML, you name it. There are loads of decent writers and parsers out there.

Comment: @MCEmperor that is a great idea thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially serializing and deserializing.

The problem with your current approach, that is, using a special token to separate different parts of the body, is that it could lead to errors if that very same token is used within such a part. One can never be sure that the separator will be unique.

That's why people invented the concept of serialization. **JSON** is a widely used format, see [json.org](http://www.json.org/). There are also plenty of parsers for that, for example [Gson](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html).

Suppose you have the following class:

```
class Message {

    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private String text;

}
```

then it can be serialized into this:

```
{
    "sender": "me",
    "receiver": "you",
    "text": "Almost any char can occur inside this, even \" or \\. They are simply escaped"
}
```

with a snippet of code like this:

```
Message message = new Message("me", "you",
    "Almost any char can occur inside this, even \" or \\. They are simply escaped");
    // The Java language itself uses the same escape sequences as JSON.
    // It actually works the same way

// Surprisingly easy to convert Java object to JSON
new Gson().toJson(message);
```

See? The receiving party can then deserialize it using this snippet:

```
new Gson().fromJson(receivedString, Message.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put the strings together, you could escape the fields and replace the dollars with some escape sequence (`\d` for instance), and unescape them when reading.